# What should I do with BackOffInterruptedException in Spring's RetryTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, retrytemplate

I'm going through automatic error reports from my desktop application, and I have this exception which I'm not sure how to handle:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
    at org.springframework.retry.backoff.ThreadWaitSleeper.sleep(ThreadWaitSleeper.java:30)
    at org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy.backOff(ExponentialBackOffPolicy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)

org.springframework.retry.backoff.BackOffInterruptedException: Thread interrupted while sleeping; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy.backOff(ExponentialBackOffPolicy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
```

The code uses Spring's [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html) with an [ExponentialBackOffPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/retry/backoff/ExponentialBackOffPolicy.html). I understand the sleeping thread got interrupted, but I don't know why, and thus, I don't know what I should do about it. If the application was exiting, then, silently swallowing that exception would be appropriate. If something stopped working and need restarting, then, I should do that; but I was hopping that RetryTemplate would already do that for me in all situations where it makes sense. I don't want to retry around RetryTemplate.

Comment: If it wasn't you that called interrupt() on your thread then you can never detect why it happened and in my case I just assume that someone or something is shutting me down so I get out of whatever I'm doing cleanly without logging exceptions that would cause calls from our tech support desk.